# Word press cutting sliding images - not displaying the entire image

Tags: images

Hi fellow Wordpressers!

So, I'm having a bit of a problem with my slider image on  my home page:

So basically when uploading my images I make sure that they are already the correct size that's required. In this case it's 1600 x 900px.

It uploads fine, and in editor mode I can see the full image but as soon as I look on my live site then it's cut about 1/4 of my image off at the bottom of the picture.

Funny thing is that in the mobile view the image displays perfectly!

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of the slider.

Comment: Also, can you give a link to the site?

Comment: what theme and/or plugin are you using foir the silder?